# How to create a local mirror of public Jenkins update site?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We are running Jenkins on a server that does not have internet access (even through proxy).
Installing and keeping the Jenkins installation up-to-date is a pain!

My idea was to make a local mirror of the complete Jenkins public update-site through a Windows workstation that has internet access. And then make this local mirror available to Jenkins through NFS share.

So my questions: How to make the local mirror?
Do you have a better/simpler idea to keep the Jenkins installation up-to-date?

Comment: In another comment, someone mentioned update-center.json.  Note that this file is digitally signed for a specific URL.  See [this site](https://github.com/ikedam/backend-update-center2/wiki/How-to-create-your-own-Jenkins-Update-Center) for how to re-generate and sign this file.  Then you can use the [Update Sites plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/UpdateSites+Manager+plugin) to use your own file.  The whole procedure is currently a little too involved to summarize in an answer here, though.

Answer (score 6):

For generating update site (update-center.json) you can use https://github.com/jenkins-infra/backend-update-center2 project

My steps:

1. Generate self signed certificate

```
    openssl genrsa -out your-update-center.key 1024
    openssl req -new -x509 -days 1095 -key your-update-center.key -out your-update-center.crt
```

2. put all plugins into your Nexus 2 maven repository
3. Clone and build backend-update-center2 project
4. generate update-center.json

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.args="-id default -h /dev/null 
    -o update-center.json -repository ULR_TO_NEXUS_REPO 
    -remoteIndex .index/nexus-maven-repository-index.gz -repositoryName YOUR_REPO_NAME 
    -directLink -pretty -nowiki -key your-update-center.key 
    -certificate your-update-center.crt 
    -root-certificate your-update-center.crt"
```

3. publish your update-center.json. Has to be accessible via http/https
4. copy generated your-update-center.crt to the JENKINS_HOME/update-center-rootCAs folder
5. "Jenkins → Plugin manage → Advanced → Update site" define link to the published update-center.json

PS. don't forget to generate and publish Nexus 2 nexus-maven-repository-index.gz index file. Use the "Publish the indexes" task for that.

Some additional information about Updater Center you can find at https://github.com/ikedam/backend-update-center2/wiki/How-to-create-your-own-Jenkins-Update-Center

Comment: This can be part of the solution once the plugin are accessible locally. But is there a way to automatically mirror the plugins from the public Jenkins plugin repository?

Answer (score 1):

Where is the issue in downloading the war file manually, stopping the server, replacing the war, and starting the server again? The same is true for Plugins.

if I think about it, there is probably a better way, by having a sandbox Jenkins on a system that has access to the internet. You update the server using the UI and then you can test that updated Jenkins thoroughly. When done, you just need to copy the war and hpi files over to your 'production' Jenkins. now you have even a nice process and QA in place.

Comment: The problem is I don't want to do it manually each time I want to update. I would like a way to automate the whole upgrade process. But you are right I was thinking about managing the whole jenkins installation in some kind of repository, updating it from another system and pushing the changes once the update is OK. But I though it may have some features in Jenkins to help managing this.

Comment: create a job that pushes the changes from your sandbox Jenkins to the production Jenkins.

Comment: If you notice in Plugins/Advanced, there is a setting for the update URL, which returns some kind of JSON. You might be able to have your mirror get this file, use it to download all the plugins necessary locally, then rewrite it and expose a modified version of the JSON pointing to the local copies. Not all that different from mirroring a NuGet server.