# Update Jenkins Plugins via Artifactory

Tags: jenkins, artifactory

I want to update Jenkins plugin via Artifactory.

1. Create a remote repo named Jenkins-update
2. Create a local repo named jenkins-update-center
3. Get the update-center.json from repo Jenkins-update to local and modify the URL from 'http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/' to my own URL 'https://artifacts.xxx.com/artifactory/Jenkins-update/' in update-center.json, then put update-center.json into local repo.

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   curl -L -o /tmp/update-center.json http://localhost:8081/artifactory/Jenkins-update-cache/update-center.json
   sed -i 's#http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/#https://artifacts.xxx.com/artifactory/Jenkins-update/#g' /tmp/update-center.json
   curl -L -uuser:pass -T /tmp/update-center.json "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/jenkins-update-center/update-center.json"
   ```
4. Change the default update site from 'http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/' to 'https://artifacts.xxx.com/artifactory/jenkins-update-center/update-center.json' in Jenkins

There is an error 'SHA-512 digest mismatch: expected=49a22dc23f739a76623d10128b6803f79e0489de3ded0f1d01f3dfba4557136c7f318baaf4749a7713ec4b3f56633f2ac3afc4703e87d423ede029d68f84c74d in 'update site 'default''' when I click 'check now' button.

What should I do to make Jenkins update plugins from Artifactory?

Tkx

Answer (score 0):

As soon as the content of update-center.json changed you need to re-generate "signature" section of this file.
For that you need to generate your key pair (see more details in [How to create a local mirror of public Jenkins update site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20128118/how-to-create-a-local-mirror-of-public-jenkins-update-site))

Also you may use the following proposed approach :

> there is probably a better way, by having a sandbox Jenkins on a system that has access to the internet. You update the server using the UI and then you can test that updated Jenkins thoroughly. When done, you just need to copy the war and hpi files over to your 'production' Jenkins. now you have even a nice process and QA in place.

Another way is to setup a transparent https proxy between your Jenkins and Artifactory server - in that case update-center.json will not change and signature verification should work fine.

With best regards,

Dmytro Gorbunov

Comment: Maybe in 2019 this was working well. But as of 2023-01-10 nothing works.
There are bunch of projects referenced to get proper json file, but there are no clear documentations how to step by step make it working.

UpdateSites Manager - v. 2.0.0 released 7 years ago. No continuity.
This one references: https://github.com/ikedam/backend-update-center2 which is only for nexus and not for ARTIFACTORY as requested in the question.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2023-01-10 there is a problem with making a mirror of the jenkins plugins on artifactory.

Artifactory documentation decribes only how to create a mirror: https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-configure-artifactory-as-a-mirror-for-jenkins-plugins/

But this is not a complete solution. Because this leads to the situation when every plugin shall be manually updated. Having plugins with bunch of dependencies it is huge effort.

There is a need to generate a file: update-center.json

There is an internal jenkins tool to do this: https://github.com/jenkins-infra/update-center2, but documentation is poor and contains vague statements like:

> With a few modifications it could easily be used to generate your corporate update center as well.

Without clear description, what shall be done.
I tried to follow steps and completely failed. Tool require some special environment variables, which are also not documented and so on.

So as of my experience mirroring jenkins plugins on artifactory is practically not possible. And honestly spoken, I would like to be wrong here.

Comment: There is an example available here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43369254/3155154

Comment: Did you tried this step by step? I had totaly failed. Especially that the answer related to Nexus repositories and not to Artifactory.