# Host jenkins plugins locally

Tags: jenkins

I've got a very locked down egress firewall which restricts access to sites I specify. I've noticed the addresses I've specified show that there's an update available for plugins, but are incapable of retrieving the .hpi file. I can extend it, but tcpdump details a variety of endpoints, I'd rather not open up egress to the half the internet.

So my question is: Can I host the plugins myself and sync these plugins from from a single jenkins source address? Is there an accepted way of doing this? I've read about running a jenkins job to [change the json file](https://www.north-47.com/knowledge-base/update-jenkins-plugins-behind-a-corporate-proxy/) (messy). Anyone got anything better

Comment: What you are seeing is it trying to find the nearest/best available [mirror.](https://www.jenkins.io/download/mirrors/) You should only need one, providing it's available.

Comment: Mirrors do not supply a consistent result. What would happen if a newer/faster mirror endpoint was created? I'd be pointed to the newer quicker endpoint and my egress firewall would fail because it wouldn't be aware of the new endpoint. Back to step one... I've no idea how many mirrors they are, what metric they use to determine speed or how consistent the results are.

Comment: From prior link, "Currently releases are mirrored to the locations documented on the [mirror status page](https://get.jenkins.io/war/2.325/jenkins.war?mirrorstats)". It's a short list, but one that's good enough is good enough. Do you not have a [corporate proxy](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/JenkinsBehindProxy)?

Comment: No proxy, no. The egress firewall has one rule for jenkins (.jenkins-ci.org). If I add a single mirror what are the implications of that mirror failing or a faster mirror becoming available? Or are you suggesting I just continually change the firewall to reflect this webpage?... Is there honestly no other option? No local mirror sync with [archives](https://archives.jenkins-ci.org/plugins/)? This is a tightly locked down firewall, I don't know if I could justify adding 9 more urls to the current 8.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a local mirror of public Jenkins update site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20128118/how-to-create-a-local-mirror-of-public-jenkins-update-site)

Comment: @NoamHelmer Well I'm not using nexus and this doesn't have instructions on how to clone, but I think I can certainly work with this, thanks!